# How to know what glassfish is - full plaform or web profile?

Tags: java, glassfish

I have installed glassfish. I can run

```
asadmin version
```

It shows what version it is, but how to know it is "Full Platform" or "Web profile"?

Comment: Well don't you know what you've downloaded?

Comment: I did not download it by myself.

Comment: see also `https://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html` and, the two downloads will have different names.  (before they're unzipped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the license file name to determine if it is Full profile or Web profile

```
<glassfish install dir>/glassfish/legal/3RD-PARTY-LICENSE.txt
<glassfish install dir>/glassfish/legal/3RD-PARTY-LICENSE-WEB-PROFILE.txt
```

Comment: Glassfish 4.1.1 only have 3RD-PARTY-LICENSE-WEB-PROFILE.txt in both profiles.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the

```
glassfish4\bin>asadmin list-containers
```

command. Which lists all known application containers. A full profile server reports this:

```
jpa
jpa
web
weld
weld
security
grizzly
ear
ejb
osgi
resources_ear
resources
appclient
webservices
connector
```

A web profile server reports this:

```
jpa
jpa
web
weld
weld
security
grizzly
ejb
osgi
resources_ear
resources
connector
```

Not much difference but it should be enough ;)

Comment: one moment that glassfish server should run

Answer (score 0):

1. **GlassFish Web Profile**: It is a lighter version of GlassFish that is designed for web applications and only includes a subset of the Java EE technologies.
2. **GlassFish Full Platform**: It is the complete version of GlassFish that includes all Java EE technologies.

Which one to download depends on the requirements of your project. If you are developing a web application and do not need the full Java EE stack, then the GlassFish Web Profile would be a good choice. If you are developing a more complex application that requires the full Java EE stack, then the GlassFish Full Platform would be a better choice.